How can an application running in a docker container listen on a port when using the '--network host' option?
I have an application that binds to a port and listens for incoming connections. This application runs inside a docker container and has been working when using the --publish 8000:8000 argument to expose the listening port and allow connections from outside the docker container. Recently we needed to add the --network host option so that the server running inside the docker container can access other interfaces outside of the docker container. However --publish and --network host dont seem to work together.
According to the docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/#examples this example below should work:
In one terminal run:
docker run --network host --rm --tty --interactive ubuntu:trusty nc -lkv 0.0.0.0 8000
In another terminal run, then type something to send:
nc localhost 8000
This example does not work, the client running in the second terminal is never able to connect to the server running in the docker.
If the server is run without --network host and add --publish 8000:8000 like this:
docker run --publish 8000:8000 --rm --tty --interactive ubuntu:trusty nc -lkv 0.0.0.0 8000
Then the client can connect, but my application needs both, it needs to listen on a port and have access to other interfaces on the host.
The firewall is off:
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

I am using docker engine (not docker desktop) on Ubuntu 22.04:
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           26.1.3
 API version:       1.45
 Go version:        go1.21.10
 Git commit:        b72abbb
 Built:             Thu May 16 08:33:29 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           rootless

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          26.1.3
  API version:      1.45 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.21.10
  Git commit:       8e96db1
  Built:            Thu May 16 08:33:29 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.32
  GitCommit:        8b3b7ca2e5ce38e8f31a34f35b2b68ceb8470d89
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.12
  GitCommit:        v1.1.12-0-g51d5e94
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
 rootlesskit:
  Version:          2.0.2
  ApiVersion:       1.1.1
  NetworkDriver:    slirp4netns
  PortDriver:       builtin
  StateDir:         /run/user/1000/dockerd-rootless
 slirp4netns:
  Version:          1.0.1
  GitCommit:        6a7b16babc95b6a3056b33fb45b74a6f62262dd4


UPDATE *
If I run the server using sudo then it works as expected, so I suspect this has something to do with running as the rootless context.

This works:
In one terminal run:
sudo docker run --network host --rm --tty --interactive ubuntu:trusty nc -lkv 0.0.0.0 8000
In another terminal run, then type something to send:
nc localhost 8000

If you are using sudo, it should work for you with root user permission. Another possible solution is to use the --cap-add option to add the necessary capabilities to the Docker container to allow it to bind to privileged ports (ports below 1024) without running as the root user. For example, you can add the NET_BIND_SERVICE capability to the Docker container like this:
docker run --cap-add=NET_BIND_SERVICE --network host --rm --tty --interactive ubuntu:trusty nc -lkv 0.0.0.0 8000

I don't know why sudo makes a difference here, but you should get a warning that --network host and --publish conflict – since host networking completely disables Docker's networking layer, you can't choose to not publish a port or to remap it.  Host networking is almost never necessary and only really works on the specific Docker/host-OS combination you have, is it possible to turn that off?

Adding --cap-add=NET_BIND_SERVICE without sudo has the same problem. Yes I do see the warning when using both --publish and --network host so I remove the --publish argument when using --network host. I need --network host because in the actual application (not netcat) it needs to be able to connect to another non container network interface that is running on the computer.
